# Html2Canvas foreignObjectRendering only render viewpoint

Tags: javascript, html, angular, canvas, html2canvas

I'm currently having issues while rendering complex DIV element into CANVAS element using Html2Canvas package.
The problem is the DIV I want to write to the CANVAS, has

```
overflow: auto
```

So the DIV is bigger than the screen ratio.
and to add gasoline to the fire, all described above is in the Angular 5 component, what means the CSS isn't available while I'm accessing to `ElementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML`.

`Encapsulation.None` didn't work for me here either.

HTML to canvas settings:

```
  async: true,
  logging: false,
  backgroundColor: null,
  allowTaint: true,
  foreignObjectRendering: true,
  removeContainer: true
```

result:
[image: result with foreignObjectRendering: true]

make attention to the black space around the image, is the screen ratio, but it couldn't be rendered.

While I'm setting:

```
foreignObjectRendering: false
```

I'm getting very satisfying quality and the dimensions I want.
but the diagrams look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance! 
this is very important to me.
And I guarantee that if I will resolve this, I'll create a very useful NPM package to export elements as PDF file at Angular 2+

Also attaching Html2Canvas documentation for your convenient:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration/

Comment: don't you find any solution for this?