# How to convert HTML with images into PDF

Tags: angular

We need to download HTML with images into Pdf file.

We have used html2canvas and jsPDF for this, But it's exporting only HTML, Some images also used in HTML, Those images are not coming in Pdf file.

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

downloadPdf() {
    var data = document.getElementById('v-9');
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
        var imgWidth = canvas.width > 198 ? 198 : canvas.width;
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
        var position = 5;
        pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 5, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
        pdf.save('file.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
    });
}

<button id="roomChildrenClear" class="btn btn-block" type="button" (click)="downloadPdf()">Download</button>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="v-9" width="100%" height="100%">
<g id="v-10" class="joint-viewport">
    <g model-id="a3bf26bd-bdbf-4e3a-84e9-7ba266a33f59" id="j_4" class="joint-cell joint-type-basic joint-type-basic-image joint-element joint-theme-default" data-type="basic.Image" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" transform="translate(1,1)">
        <g class="rotatable" id="v-26">
            <g class="scalable" transform="scale(3.125,3.125)">
                <image id="v-28" xlink:href="../../images/icons/door.png" width="16" height="16"></image>
            </g>
            <text id="v-27" font-size="14" display="none" xml:space="preserve" y="0.8em" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-family="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,25,70)">
            <tspan id="v-29" class="v-line v-empty-line" dy="0em" style="fill-opacity: 0; stroke-opacity: 0;">-</tspan>
        </text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g model-id="c4349d44-5b4e-4d3b-ba73-73691cd88c29" id="j_5" class="joint-cell joint-type-basic joint-type-basic-rect joint-element joint-theme-default" data-type="basic.Rect" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" transform="translate(1,1)">
        <g class="rotatable" id="v-30">
            <g class="scalable" transform="scale(0.5,0.8333333333333334)">
                <rect id="v-31" fill="#1240AB" stroke="#1240AB" width="100" height="60" stroke-miterlimit="10" dbid="doorid123:0" fill-opacity="0.03"></rect>
            </g>
            <text id="v-32" font-size="14" display="none" xml:space="preserve" y="0.8em" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,25,25)">
            <tspan id="v-33" class="v-line v-empty-line" dy="0em" style="fill-opacity: 0; stroke-opacity: 0;">-</tspan>
        </text>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<defs id="v-11"></defs>
</svg>
```

Actual: Image icon not showing in the pdf file.

[image: Pdf image]

Expected: Image icon should show in the pdf file. 
[image: HTML with image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting these config to the options parameter:

```
html2canvas(data, {
useCORS: true,
foreignObjectRendering: true,
allowTaint: true
})
```

If this does not work for you, I'm attaching a link to docs here:
https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration

there are situations that trying fine-tune those options config, will give satisfying results.

I was facing this problem by myself while trying the same on my Angular 5 application and solved it by accessing my own application using puppeteer.
You can try puppeteer as well: https://pptr.dev

Link to the discussion about my problem:
[Html2Canvas foreignObjectRendering only render viewpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563864/html2canvas-foreignobjectrendering-only-render-viewpoint)
[Html2Canvas foreignObjectRendering only render viewpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563864/html2canvas-foreignobjectrendering-only-render-viewpoint)

Hope my answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks, @Cod3n0d3 for your reply, Now I am using base64 in img src, the issue gets resolved using base64 in src.